# c# get shape in selected group set on a slide

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint

*Intro:* I'm new in C# coding, just searching code and trying to get it together.

*Question:* Can you tell me how to get programmatically one shape from two grouped shapes? Or give me the link with explanation? I've been searching this for two days already and it's drive me a crazy :(.

*Situation:* I'm writing PowerPoint Add-In that insert 2 shapes on slide, group them and the next button modifes one of shape from those selected group set. And I've got stuck with how to get selected one shape from the group set. 
I found and modifyed this code, but it works for any shape on the slide, even if it's not a group set:

```
var AppPPT = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
if (AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.Type == PowerPoint.PpSelectionType.ppSelectionShapes)
{
    PowerPoint.Shape shape = AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange[1];
    shape.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Office.MsoThemeColorIndex.msoThemeColorAccent2;
}
```

I have this add-in in VBA and it works fine, but I wanted to re-write this in C#.

```
Sub Change()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shpG As ShapeRange
Dim oShp As Shape
    Set oShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)    
    oShp.GroupItems(2).Visible = msoTrue
    oShp.GroupItems(2).Select msoTrue

    With oShp.GroupItems(2)
    //changes with the shape
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks, 
Elena

Comment: If you have the working VBA version, it would be useful to include that.

Comment: I've added VBA code in original post. Thanks

Comment: You can use `ShapeRange.GroupItems.Count` to see how many shapes there are associated with the ShapeRange. If >1 then you can query out a specific shape from the collection using (eg) `ShapeRange.GroupItems(2)`

Comment: @TimWilliams It works, thanks! 
My code now is
`PowerPoint.Shape shapeRange = AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange[1];
                if (shapeRange.GroupItems.Count >1) {shapeRange.GroupItems[2].Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Office.MsoThemeColorIndex.msoThemeColorAccent2;}`